# how to have a zoom effect on hover

Tags: html, css

Well all i want is to have a slide up text with a zoom in light grey filter
so when i hover on the text slide up and a filter zoom in same motion as the image here is a codepen project it shows what i mean sadly i cant figure it out thanks in advance here is the link : [Codepen exemple](https://codepen.io/jabelmunoz/pen/QpMrbL)
Thanks in advance

```css
.clients{

    position: relative;
}

.client-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .client-container .product-desc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-align: right;
    padding: 14em 0.4em 0.2em;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(101%);
    transform: translateY(101%);
    transition: -webkit-transform 1sms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1sms ease-in-out;
  }


  .client-container:hover .product-desc {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }

  .client-container .product-desc2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 17em 0.4em 0.2em;
    -webkit-transform: translateY(101%);
    transform: translateY(101%);
    transition: -webkit-transform 1sms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1sms ease-in-out;
  }


  .client-container:hover .product-desc2 {
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0);
    transform: translateY(0);
  }
  
  .brand-img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -o-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  
  .clients:hover .brand-img{    
    cursor: pointer;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="clients col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3">
              <a href="#">
                <figure class="client-container">
                  <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://1757140519.rsc.cdn77.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/jpg.png" alt="Logo">
                  <figcaption class="product-desc"><P>2022 all rights reserved</P></figcaption>
                  <figcaption class="product-desc2"><h4>name</h4></figcaption>
                </figure>
              </a>
            </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the `opacity: 0;` to set your text invisible. You can now change the the `opacity` to `1` on the hover when you want to have it visible. For the zoom effect, you can use `transform: scale(x);`.

Here is an example with your code:

```css
.clients{

    position: relative;
}

.client-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
  }

  .client-container .product-desc {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    text-align: right;
    padding: 14em 0.4em 0.2em;
   opacity: 0;
     transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -o-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }


  .client-container:hover .product-desc {
   cursor: pointer;
   opacity: 1;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:scale(1.5);
  }

  .client-container .product-desc2 {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: left;
    align-items: center;
    color: #fff;
    opacity: 0;
    text-align: right;
    padding: 17em 0.4em 0.2em;
    
    transition: -webkit-transform 1sms ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out;
    transition: transform 1s ease-in-out, -webkit-transform 1sms ease-in-out;
    
  }


  .client-container:hover .product-desc2 {
    cursor: pointer;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:scale(1.5);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  
  .brand-img {
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    transform:scale(1);
    -ms-transform:scale(1);
    -moz-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1);
    -o-transform:scale(1);
    -webkit-transition: all 1.5s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1s ease;
    transition: all 1s ease;
  }
  
  .clients:hover .brand-img{    
    cursor: pointer;
    transform:scale(1.5);
    -ms-transform:scale(1.5);
    -moz-transform:scale(1.5);
    -webkit-transform:scale(1.2);
    -o-transform:scale(1.5);
}
```

```html
<div class="clients col-6 col-md-4 col-lg-3 col-lg-3">
              <a href="#">
                <figure class="client-container">
                  <img class="img-fluid brand-img" src="https://1757140519.rsc.cdn77.org/blog/wp-content/uploads/2013/06/jpg.png" alt="Logo">
                  <figcaption class="product-desc"><P>2022 all rights reserved</P></figcaption>
                  <figcaption class="product-desc2"><h4>name</h4></figcaption>
                </figure>
              </a>
            </div>
```

Comment: Technically it worked but the desc1 and desc2 are acting weird now :/